# How to select one of several power queries to load an Excel table

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have an Excel workbook that allows the user to explore the imported data and generate a chart. The input information comes in the form of a CSV file.

The CSV file layout changes according to the vendor and the class of data produced, however all the information I require is contained within the CSV and a consistent layout can be obtained using Power Query to reformat, rename and filter columns.

The resulting data consist of rows with a couple of labels and then a series of readings across a number of columns (typically 10 or 20).

I'm looking for advice on how to manage serially importing the different input files using Excel/VBA/Power Query. I don't want to create a workbook for each input file format. Each imported data replaces the previous analysis.

Conceptually I have the following:

```
On the 'Input' Sheet -> button for input format 1, button for input format 2, etc.

VBA to use file open dialog to get the name of the chosen input file

Power Query -> one per input file format

'Working' Sheet -> the data loaded from the PowerQuery and the a chart based on that data.
```

So far I can import one file format, I'm not sure where to handle these choices, specifically each power query returns data into a separate excel table/sheet.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

No need for VBA. Have a named range cell in Excel with a drop-down for the data source. Use "load from table or range" to access that named cell in power query.

Now in a new blank query referencing this value, use an `if` statement to switch between the N different queries you have and return whichever corresponds to the drop down as the result of the blank query.

Whenever you change the drop down you can use VBA to trigger a refresh, or if you add a column to the query showing data source, you can use an excel formula to detect when the drop down is different from the query result and indicate to the user that a refresh is required.